# Trigonometry problem gives a wrong answer

Tags: trigonometry

[image: img]

A. Find the BC.

Information: <) BAC = 65 (the base), AD = 10

I could not get it to work.

What I did is, I took `ADB` and then I divided `65` by 2 so `BAD = 32.5`.

Now I need to find BD so I did

```
tan (32.5) * 10 = 6.37 * 2 = 12.74
```

so BC = 12.74, but in the book the answer is 8.12, what did I do wrong?

Comment: because you are assuming that AD is bisector, which is not given moreover AD is not perpendicular to BC, at least it is not given

Comment: I think you need another piece of information.  So far you only have an angle and a side.  Are $AE$ and $CE$ altitudes?

Comment: What is $E$? Is the triangle isosceles? How is $D$ defined?

Comment: The length of AD to the base BC is 10 cm